# .htaccess works but ignores one rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use .htaccess and mod_rewrite to redirect http requests. For instance:

```
RewriteRule ^tutoring/?$ path/to/tutoring.php [L,NC]
```

I know that the Rewrite Engine is on because all but one rule are correctly executed. However there is one rule that is not being executed properly by the server and I'm hoping to figure out why. The rule written as:

```
RewriteRule ^solutions?/?$ path/to/solutions.php [L,NC]
```

The URL example.com/solution is correctly redirected. However example.com/solutions returns a 404 error. I tried to modify the rule to target the specific URL that isn't working:

```
RewriteRule ^solutions$ path/to/solutions.php [L,NC]
```

I get the same results: a `404 error`. I also tried deleting all the other .htaccess commands except for this last rule (along with RewriteEngine on) but still, the server is ignoring the rule (or more accurately only partially enforcing it since `/solution` is redirected but `/solutions` is not)

I have no idea why this could be happening, especially since all the other rules work. The problematic rule in question works on my development machine.  In my research I've only come across cases of rewrite not working for any rule, rather than working for all but a specific rule.

Where should I look for the source of the problem? The site is hosted on an Apache 2.4 VPS

//////////////////  EDIT:  /////////////////
The Apache error log shows
`AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /home/username/public_html/solutions (None could be negotiated).`

I've tried to enable rewrite log by adding the following lines to .htaccess, but they cause a 500 error. Don't know what else to do:
`RewriteLog “/home/username/public_html/rewrite.log`
`RewriteLogLevel 5`

//////////////////  RESOLVED:  /////////////////
I discovered that a file named solutions.html.BAK in my web root directory was causing the problem. Trying to GET "example.com/solutions" would cause the server to try to match the Rewrite rules against "solutions.html.BAK" instead of "solutions". After none of the rules matched this request, a 404 error would ensue. Deleting solutions.html.BAK resolved the issue.

Comment: Is the `/path/to` part different from the document root?

Comment: `path/to`is a sub-directory. Other rules that redirect to the same path work. In fact, `/solution` is properly redirected while `/solutions` is not, even though they are matched by the same rule!  `RewriteRule ^solutions?/?$`

Comment: is there a solutions.php in your root?

Comment: No. Just did a search for all php files with 'solutions' in the name. In the web root, there are np_my_solutions.php and np_solutions.php.  The only file named solutions.php is the one I'm trying to redirect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jon Lin,

Your questions were incredibly helpful and I've figured out how to fix my problem, though I still don't know what was the problem.

RewriteLog wouldn't work in my conf file because it has been removed from my version of Apache (2.4). See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html.  To turn on mod_rewrite logging, the command I used is `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3` . This adds rewrite log entries to the error log. (a separate log would have been better but I don't know how to make one)

Remember, my problem was that `RewriteRule ^solutions?/?$  bs3/pages/solutions.php` would match example.com/solution, but not example.com/solutions.

:::::::::::::::From the Logs::::::::::
Requesting `example.com/solutions` would add the following to the log:

```
strip per-dir prefix: /home/username/public_html/solutions.html.BAK -> solutions.html.BAK
applying pattern '^solutions?/?$' to uri 'solutions.html.BAK'
```

I have no idea why the server would interpret a request for 'solutions' as 'solutions.html.BAK'.  Since this BAK was a file in my root directory, I removed it and the problem went away. Now a request for `example.com/solutions/` adds to the log:

```
strip per-dir prefix: /home/username/public_html/solutions/ -> solutions/
applying pattern '^solutions?/?$' to uri 'solutions/'
rewrite 'solutions/' -> 'bs3/pages/solutions.php'
```

Comment: It's interpreting "solutions" as "solutions.html.BAK" because of mod_negotiation. You can turn it off by turning off mutliviews or disabling mod_negotiation. Otherwise, it will look at every request and try to match it to a similar existing resource.

Answer (score 1):

You can't turn on rewrite logging from inside an htaccess file, it needs to happen in your vhost/server config.

The error you're getting seems to be related to mod_negotiation, which has to do with multi views. Try turning that off:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

and if that doesn't work, try disabling mod_negotiation in your server config.

Comment: Jon, where Should I put the rewrite log directive? Putting `RewriteLog` command within <VirtualHost> prevents the server from starting.

Comment: Logs told me that `RewriteLog` is an unknown command. I learned from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html that it has been removed and replaced with `LogLevel alert rewrite`. Once I could turn on mod rewrite logs, I figured out what was going on. Thanks for guiding me

Comment: Thanks mate This solved the same problem for me in apache 2.4 I just installed 2 days ago.